# How come the =STDEV formula is not equal to the standard deviation that I enter in the normsdist formula

Tags: excel

I've calculated the normdist of values between -5 and 5 with intervals of 0.25 using the =NORMDIST formula with mean = 0 and sigma = 1.

When I use the =STDEV on the result column, I get something closer to 0.132.

I was expecting a value of 1. what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`NORMDIST(z)` gives the height of a bell curve corresponding to a random normal's probability distribution function.

If you take the Standard Deviation of these heights, you are not finding the Standard Deviation of the random normal variable.

You can find the standard deviation of a random variable from values, and probabilities of those values, but not with the STDEV function. All STDEV does is give you the square root of 1/N  (or possibly `1/(N-1)`?) of the squared difference from the mean of the values you supplied.

To see that this is a mistake that can't possibly work, first notice that the output of `NORMDIST(z)` must always be greater than 0 for all z. Therefore the `mean` of the output is greater than 0, and mismatches the assumption that `mean=0`.

The STDEV function operates on a set of values, and assuming they are normal, converges towards the sigma that produced them.  It does not operate on probability values, but on realizations.

So if you want to generate random normal (0,1) variables, so you can check them with STDEV, what you should do in the generation cells is call `=NORMSINV(RAND())` and copy that call down a large number of cells (100s).  Then take the `STDEV()` of that data.  That actually generates random normal variables because RAND() generates uniform random variables in `[0,1]` and `NORMSINV()` is the inverse cumulative distribution function.

If you play with this, note it still needs lots of cells to converge to SDEV = 1.